# Sorting strings into new lines and single quote marks using UNIX commands

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a bunch of text that can look something like this:

```
K1      CM1     TN1     CT14    D01
K2      CM2     TN2     CT15    D02
K3      CM3     TN3     CT16    D03
K4      CM4     TN4     CT17    D04
K5      CM5     TN5     CT18    D05
K6      CM6     TN6     CT19    D06
K7      CM11    TN7     CT20    D07
K8      CM12    TN8             D08
TW10    CM15    TN9             D09
TW11            TN10            D11
TW12            TN11            D12
TW16            TN12            D6W
```

**(columns may be empty and are separated by a single tab, not spaces -- cas)**

I would like to use the Run Unix command feature in BBedit to transform this text into the following:

```
'K1',
'K2',
'K3',
'K4',
'K5',
'K6',
'K7',
'K8',
'TW10',
'TW11',
'TW12',
'TW16',
'CM1',
'CM2',
'CM3',
'CM4',
'CM5',
'CM6',
'CM11',
'CM12',
'CM15',
'TN1',
'TN2',
'TN3',
'TN4',
'TN5',
'TN6',
'TN7',
'TN8',
'TN9',
'TN10',
'TN11',
'TN12',
'CT14',
'CT15',
'CT16',
'CT17',
'CT18',
'CT19',
'CT20',
'D01',
'D02',
'D03',
'D04',
'D05',
'D06',
'D07',
'D08',
'D09',
'D11',
'D12',
'D6W'
```

As you can see, each string is surrounded by single quotation marks and followed by a comma apart from the final string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The engine of the site [converted tab characters to spaces](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5797/108618). This is unfortunate, for now I cannot edit and fix this for you. Until someone who can does, users who want to copy the snippet should use [this source link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/306c1d50-4386-425b-a7dd-f16524e711cf/view-source). The tabs are there.

Comment: So the input has tab-separated fields, and the output should contain the first field from each line (top to bottom), then the second field from each line, etc. plus the quotes, skipping any empty fields?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain, in words, how you get from your example input to the desired output. Something like what @ilkkachu wrote above. Also tell us your operating system. BBedit seems to be some kind of macOS-specific text editor, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input contains lines with tab-separated fields, and you want first the first field from each line top to bottom, then the second field, etc., plus the quotes and commas, here are some cheap solutions.

Ugly two-liner for max 9 columns (with sed for formatting):

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do cut -f$i file.txt; done | 
    grep -v '^$' | sed  -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/\$/'/" -e '$!s/$/,/'
```

Manually transposing with AWK (plus sed to remove the last comma):

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF > cols {cols=NF}
                      {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { a[i,NR]=$i }} 
            END { for (j=1;j<=cols;j++) for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)
                      if (a[j, i] != "") printf "\047%s\047,\n", a[j, i] }' file.txt |
    sed -e '$s/,$//'
```

With GNU datamash (and sed for formatting):

```
datamash --no-strict transpose < file.txt | tr -s '\t' '\n' |
    sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/\$/'/" -e '$!s/$/,/'
```

(tested on Linux, the first two also work on macOS)

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try this method that uses grep and sed:

```
for i in K TW CM TN CT D ;do grep -ow $i[0-9]*[A-Z]* <input_file;done
```

If you want to put each item in single quotes and add a comma at the end of each line as well then pipe the above to this command:

```
sed "s/$/\'\,/" | sed "s/^/\'/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is tab-delimited in columns:

```
K1      CM1     TN1     CT14    D01
K2      CM2     TN2     CT15    D02
K3      CM3     TN3     CT16    D03
K4      CM4     TN4     CT17    D04
K5      CM5     TN5     CT18    D05
K6      CM6     TN6     CT19    D06
K7      CM11    TN7     CT20    D07
K8      CM12    TN8             D08
TW10    CM15    TN9             D09
TW11            TN10            D11
TW12            TN11            D12
TW16            TN12            D6W
```

... we may transpose the tab-delimited columns into rows (still with tab-delimited fields) using GNU `datamash` (available for macOS via e.g. Homebrew), then replace the tabs with newlines using `tr`, and then finally insert single quotes and commas appropriately:

```bash
$ datamash transpose <file | tr -s '\t' '\n' | sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/',/"
'K1',
'K2',
'K3',
'K4',
'K5',
'K6',
'K7',
'K8',
'TW10',
```

(etc.)

The `-s` option to `tr` ensures that multiple consecutive newlines are squeezed into single ones in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure what `the Run Unix command feature in BBedit` means but if you're just looking for a Unix command to produce the output you show from the input you show then - using any awk and assuming your fields are separated by tabs:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
{
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        if ( $i != "" ) {
            a[i,NR] = $i
            max_j[i] = NR
        }
    }
    max_i = (max_i > NF ? max_i : NF)
}
END {
    for ( i=1; i<=max_i; i++ ) {
        for ( j=1; j<=max_j[i]; j++ ) {
            printf "%s\047%s\047", sep, a[i,j]
            sep = ",\n"
        }
    }
    print ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
'K1',
'K2',
'K3',
'K4',
'K5',
'K6',
'K7',
'K8',
'TW10',
'TW11',
'TW12',
'TW16',
'CM1',
'CM2',
'CM3',
'CM4',
'CM5',
'CM6',
'CM11',
'CM12',
'CM15',
'TN1',
'TN2',
'TN3',
'TN4',
'TN5',
'TN6',
'TN7',
'TN8',
'TN9',
'TN10',
'TN11',
'TN12',
'CT14',
'CT15',
'CT16',
'CT17',
'CT18',
'CT19',
'CT20',
'D01',
'D02',
'D03',
'D04',
'D05',
'D06',
'D07',
'D08',
'D09',
'D11',
'D12',
'D6W'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl:

```
$ perl -lne '
    # split each input line on single tabs (not one-or-more
    # whitespace chars) into temporary array @F.
    @F = split /\t/;

    # Construct an Array-of-Arrays (AoA) containing the data.
    # This works with any number of columns, not limited to 5.
    # Assumes each input line has the same number of fields,
    # although some may be empty.
    foreach my $i (keys @F) {
        if (length($F[$i]) > 0) {
          push @{$columns[$i]}, "\047" . $F[$i] ."\047" ;
        };
    };

    END {
        # flatten the AoA with map and print it
        print join(",\n", map { @$_ } @columns);
    }' input.txt 
'K1',
'K2',
'K3',
'K4',
'K5',
'K6',
'K7',
'K8',
'TW10',
'TW11',
'TW12',
'TW16',
'CM1',
'CM2',
'CM3',
'CM4',
'CM5',
'CM6',
'CM11',
'CM12',
'CM15',
'TN1',
'TN2',
'TN3',
'TN4',
'TN5',
'TN6',
'TN7',
'TN8',
'TN9',
'TN10',
'TN11',
'TN12',
'CT14',
'CT15',
'CT16',
'CT17',
'CT18',
'CT19',
'CT20',
'D01',
'D02',
'D03',
'D04',
'D05',
'D06',
'D07',
'D08',
'D09',
'D11',
'D12',
'D6W'
```

This reads the input line-by-line, splits each line using a single tab as the delimiter and constructs an Array-of-Arrays called `@columns` from the non-empty columns of each line, which are surrounded by single-quotes (octal `\047`).

When the entire file has been read, it uses `map` to "flatten" (i.e. convert to a single array) and prints it with `,\n` between each element.

---

BTW, `map` is a built-in perl function for doing things to lists/arrays. It can be thought of as a fancy specialised `for` loop.  See `perldoc -f map` for details.  Reading `perldoc -f split` would also be useful if you're not familiar with perl's `split` function. And `perldoc -f join` too.

Comment: though they have K1, K2, K3... in the output, not K1, CM1, TN1...

Comment: @ilkkachu right you are, didn't notice that. so they want column1 printed first, then column2, then 3, then 4, then 5.  probably easiest to use an array of arrays for that.  complicated a little by the fact that not all input lines have 5 or even 4 columns..but a comment seems to indicate that the original file was tab-separated.  i'll edit my copy of the input file and fix my answer later today when I've got the time.

Answer (score 0):

Short Perl one liner:

```
perl -0anE'say join",\n",map{"\047$_\047"}@F' file
```

- the `-a` switch is `autosplit` mode (default on white spaces, tabs...)
- the `-0` switch is a little trick to slurp the whole file even if it's not dedicated for this purpose at the first glance. It search for non existing `\0` null byte.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = [Z] lines>>.split("\t"); .join(",\n").say for @a.map(*.grep({.chars}))>>.map: "\c[APOSTROPHE]" ~ * ~ "\c[APOSTROPHE]" ;' neo2049.txt
```

#OR

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = [Z] lines>>.split("\t"); .grep({$_.chars}).map( "\c[APOSTROPHE]" ~ * ~ "\c[APOSTROPHE]" ).join(",\n").say for @a;' neo2049.txt
```

#OR

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = ([Z] lines>>.split("\t")).map(*.grep({$_.chars}))>>.map( "\c[APOSTROPHE]" ~ * ~ "\c[APOSTROPHE]" ); .say for @a>>.join(",\n");' neo2049.txt
```

#OR

```
~$ raku -e '.join(",\n").say for ([Z] lines>>.split("\t"))>>.grep({$_.chars})>>.map( "\c[APOSTROPHE]" ~ * ~ "\c[APOSTROPHE]" );' neo2049.txt
```

#OR

```
~$ raku -e 'put ([Z] (lines>>.split( / \t / ))).flat.grep({.chars}).map({"\c[APOSTROPHE]$_\c[APOSTROPHE]"}).join(",\n");' neo2049.txt
```

Briefly, `lines` are read in and `split` on `\t` tabs. Empty elements are retained. Each word element (whether saved into an array or not) is immediately `[Z]` "zipped" transposing rows-with-columns, `grep`ped to retain non-empty elements, then wrapped with a leading and trailing `\c[APOSTROPHE]`. These wrapped elements are `join`ed on `",\n"` comma-newline, and output with `.say` (`.put` also works).

Sample Output (all 5 code examples):

```
'K1',
'K2',
'K3',
'K4',
'K5',
'K6',
'K7',
'K8',
'TW10',
'TW11',
'TW12',
'TW16'
'CM1',
'CM2',
'CM3',
'CM4',
'CM5',
'CM6',
'CM11',
'CM12',
'CM15'
'TN1',
'TN2',
'TN3',
'TN4',
'TN5',
'TN6',
'TN7',
'TN8',
'TN9',
'TN10',
'TN11',
'TN12'
'CT14',
'CT15',
'CT16',
'CT17',
'CT18',
'CT19',
'CT20'
'D01',
'D02',
'D03',
'D04',
'D05',
'D06',
'D07',
'D08',
'D09',
'D11',
'D12',
'D6W'
```

Note 1: Raku has a call `.raku` (or alternatively `.perl`) which will return elements of a list/array wrapped in double-quotes. If double-quotes are acceptable to the OP, using `.raku`/`.perl` could really simplify the code a bit.

Note 2: Be careful to do the transformations in order...it's *really* easy to mangle your data! Notably, the `[Z]` zip operator will 'skim-off' elements from the list you feed it, for example, taking the two arrays `[a,b,c]`,`[d,e,f]` and zipping together to produce `[a,d]`,`[b,e]`,`[c,f]`. But if one of the lists is 'short', the `[Z]` zip-operator will simply move to the next available element, potentially producing mis-aligned columns.

Note 3: Don't expect to copy-paste the OP's dataset and get meaningful output. The 'short' columns (with empty elements) must correspond to rows containing two consecutive `\t\t` tabs. Remember, garbage-in, garbage-out!

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Gnu sed only:

```bash
sed -r '
:2;N
:1;s/\t(\S*)(\n.*)\t/\2\n\1,/;t1
s/\n/,/;s/\n/\t/g
$!b2
s/[,\t]+/,\n/g
s/\w+/\x27&\x27/g
' file
```

From the 2 lines loaded into the buffer, we create one line of the following format:

```
K1,K2   CM1,CM2 TN1,TN2 CT14,CT15   D01,D02
```

And so on with each new line.
At the end, we format the output.

When forming can be used instead of a comma `\r \a \f \v` characters not found in text.